# Issue with using ajax to call a .php file that redirects user to different page

Tags: java, php, javascript, ajax, ssl

Hey guys so I have a TOS popup window I am creating and if the user declines a .ajax function calls a .php file which destroys their session and sends them back to login page.

This is a site protected by a SSL lock and so I get an error saying:

The page at `where the ajax function is that gets the other page with the destroy session and redirect` displayed insecure content from `the login page which is suppose to be sent to, the user.`

Function:

```
function decline(){

 $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
 /*****run ajax to kill session of current user and return to login page ******/
  $.ajax({ url: 'termsofservice/declinedkill.php',
         data: {},
         type: 'get',
         success: function(output) {
                  }
});
}
```

Here is the declinedkill.php:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

header("location:/PCG/mainlogin.php");
```

I made sure I am not using any links that would include other files, etc....  So not to sure what is wrong.

Thanks, David :)

Edit:

Here is the updated links I am using:

```
$.ajax({ url: '//mysite.com/PCG/termsofservice/declinedkill.php',
         data: {},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                  }
});
```

declinedkill.php

```
header("location:https://mysite.com/PCG/mainlogin.php");
```

So now I don't get that message but I am not getting redirected?

Comment: Ya sorry....I'll reedit that

Comment: How about not sending a redirect? Just set window.location in the success handler? You could have the AJAX call return the URL to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're site is on SSL, you need to also call the SSL URL for the script.

So like this:

```
function decline(){

 $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
 /*****run ajax to kill session of current user and return to login page ******/
  $.ajax({ url: '//yoursite.com/termsofservice/declinedkill.php',
         data: {},
         type: 'get',
         success: function(output) {
                  }
});
}
```

The // is instead of https:// or http://
It is used to automatically choose the right URI scheme.
They are called Protocol-relative URL's. [Check this link](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) to find out more on them.

Comment: Not necessary when you use protocal-relative URL's. Check my post again. You could hardcode the https url but this is better.

Comment: Use a space between the Location: and the url. `header("Location: https://mysite.com/PCG/mainlogin.php");` Also make sure the is no output (like spaces) before the header is called.

Comment: I'm actually just changing it to a javascript redirect on the success part!